# Zurb Foundation .sticky stick-to-bottom flashes at top of page on pageload

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, sticky, zurb-foundation-6

I have a cookie warning banner on my site that I want to show for users who have not seen it already (check for cookieInformation cookie and if no, show the banner). The issue is that this used to work with a window.onload function, however recently the window.onload never fires. If I use a document.ready, the banner flashes at the top of the screen before sticking to the bottom where it's supposed to be.

I would set a timeout for the function, however, if this is a foundation loading issue, the flash will still occur on slow loading.

Is there a foundation callback function like foundation.ready that I can use to invoke this function?

```
.container#cookieTin(data-sticky-container)
        .cookiebanner.is-hidden.sticky(in-view="$inview == false ? cookieAccept() : '' ", data-sticky='', data-stick-to="bottom", data-options="stickyOn: small;", data-margin-bottom="0", data-closable )
            .small-12.medium-6.columns
                strong !{ __("cookie.line_1")}
                br
                span !{ __("cookie.line_2")}
            .small-12.medium-6.columns
                a.cookieButton.button !{ __("cookie.line_3")}
                button.close-button.cookieButton(aria-label='Close alert', type='button', data-close)
                    span(aria-hidden='true') ×
```

The JS:

```
function showCookieBanner() {
        $('.cookiebanner').removeClass("is-hidden");
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".cookieButton").click(function () {
            closePopup();
        });
        var closePopup = function () {
            $('.cookiebanner').css("display", "none");
            createCookie('cookieInformation', 'seen', '15');
            return false;
        }
        if (getCookie('cookieInformation') == null) {
            showCookieBanner();
        }
    });
```

I've tried adding a .no-js class to no avail as well as eventListeners.

Comment: Please provide a working codepen so we understand and reproduce this much better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foundation 6 sticky FOUC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971831/foundation-6-sticky-fouc)