# Foundation 6 sticky FOUC

Tags: callback, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have a sticky element with data-stick-to-bottom however when I refresh the page, it flashes at the top before sticking to the bottom.

Is there a callback or a function to check if foundation is ready?

Comment: A codepen would have been good.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by adding:

```
$(window).trigger('load.zf.sticky');
```

Before calling my showBanner function.

Comment: Thanks to this post:https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/8394